# How to save the output of slurm command into a file?

Tags: cron, slurm

I have installed slurm command to track the amount of data consumed by an interface `apt install slurm`

My gold is to save its output into a file, I wrote this script to let me do that, but I did not get the expected results.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "#####################################"
date "+%F %H:%M:%S :: snapshot on interface"
timeout 5s slurm -s -i eno1 >> /home/trackeNIC.log;
```

I add this job for running the script

```
* * * * * bash /home/trackeNIC.sh >> /home/trackeNIC.log
```

The result I got is :

```
#####################################
2020-05-15 15:02:01 :: snapshot on interface
#####################################
2020-05-15 15:03:01 :: snapshot on interface
#####################################
```

I expect something like :

```
#####################################
    2020-05-15 15:02:01 :: snapshot on interface
                        -= slurm 0.4.3 =-
        x
        x
        x
      x x
     xxxx
     xxxx
     xx x
      x x
      x
      x
          Active Interface: eno1                    Interface Speed: unknown
          Current RX Speed: 141.12 KB/s            Current TX Speed: 17.63 KB/s
        Graph Top RX Speed: 876.31 KB/s          Graph Top TX Speed: 32.47 KB/s
      Overall Top RX Speed: 876.31 KB/s        Overall Top TX Speed: 32.47 KB/s
          Received Packets: 24045657            Transmitted Packets: 14187466
           GBytes Received: 21.377 GB            GBytes Transmitted: 1.381 GB
       Errors on Receiving: 0                Errors on Transmission: 0
    #####################################
    2020-05-15 15:03:01 :: snapshot on interface
                        -= slurm 0.4.3 =-
        x
        x
        x
      x x
     xxxx
     xxxx
     xx x
      x x
      x
      x
          Active Interface: eno1                    Interface Speed: unknown
          Current RX Speed: 141.12 KB/s            Current TX Speed: 17.63 KB/s
        Graph Top RX Speed: 876.31 KB/s          Graph Top TX Speed: 32.47 KB/s
      Overall Top RX Speed: 876.31 KB/s        Overall Top TX Speed: 32.47 KB/s
          Received Packets: 24045657            Transmitted Packets: 14187466
           GBytes Received: 26.377 GB            GBytes Transmitted: 2.381 GB
       Errors on Receiving: 0                Errors on Transmission: 0
    #####################################
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it help if you use `slurm` with the full path to the `slurm` executable? The `PATH` variable may well be different in the environment that cron jobs are executed compared to your interactive shell environment.

Comment: Even `timeout 5s slurm -s -i eno1 >> /home/trackeNIC.log;` does not append the output into the file.

Comment: Find the full paths of both `timeout` and `slurm` with `command -v timeout` and `command -v slurm` in an interactive shell. Then use those paths when you call those tools in your script. Does that make it work?

Comment: @Kusalananda even with the full paths it gives the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the only sure way, would be to use a program like screen or tmux.

So, you could keep your slurm running in screen, detach from the screen session and then run

```
screen -X hardcopy /tmp/tmpfile
cat /tmp/tmpfile >> final_destionation.txt
```

in a cron

you can modify screen with more options if you have multiple sessions that you need to capture, man screen helps there.

The result looks like this:

```
                     -= slurm 0.4.3 on catscrash-desktop =-

                                    x
                                    x
                                    x
                                    x
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 x x                         x      xx                    xx      xx
 x x                                x                             x
 x x                                x                             x




      Active Interface: enp3s0                  Interface Speed: unknown

      Current RX Speed: 0.73 KB/s              Current TX Speed: 1.08 KB/s
    Graph Top RX Speed: 211.54 KB/s          Graph Top TX Speed: 15.46 KB/s
  Overall Top RX Speed: 236.80 KB/s        Overall Top TX Speed: 22.95 KB/s
      Received Packets: 15711309            Transmitted Packets: 8187879
       GBytes Received: 14.754 GB            GBytes Transmitted: 1.586 GB
   Errors on Receiving: 0                Errors on Transmission: 0














                     -= slurm 0.4.3 on catscrash-desktop =-

                       x
                       x
                       x
                       x
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                  x    x                        x   x                        x
                       x                        x   x
                       x                            x
                       x



      Active Interface: enp3s0                  Interface Speed: unknown

      Current RX Speed: 2.15 KB/s              Current TX Speed: 0.57 KB/s
    Graph Top RX Speed: 226.49 KB/s          Graph Top TX Speed: 18.00 KB/s
  Overall Top RX Speed: 14187.07 KB/s      Overall Top TX Speed: 870.02 KB/s
      Received Packets: 15760792            Transmitted Packets: 8215865
       GBytes Received: 14.810 GB            GBytes Transmitted: 1.590 GB
   Errors on Receiving: 0                Errors on Transmission: 0
```

There's a lot of empty lines, so some grepping won't hurt, but it's a start